# Get information and mute/unmute auxiliary input devices

Tags: c#, .net, windows, audio

I'm trying to find a way of getting the information about auxiliary input devices for windows devices, and being able to mute/unmute them individually.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKnIy.png

In the picture you can see a "Microphone" under a playback device's "Levels" tab.

I've already tried using NAudio and WASAPI to get audio device information, but those auxiliary input devices are not listed in either, nor there is a property of the Playback MMDevice that suggests that is has an  auxiliary Input device.

Is there any other wrapper or api I should look at to find the auxiliary input devices from a given output device and mute/unmute the auxiliary input devices at will?

Using .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Well yes there is another API, that I have written, that interfaces with the Windows Mixer API found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/audio-mixer-reference. It's very simple to use, and I believe it should also solve your issue. You can enumerate all devices and controls for each device line. The code in this API is also documented using the docs right from Microsoft.

[WindowsMixer API Github](https://github.com/PoofImaFox/WindowsMixerControl)

Example To Mute all Input devices;

```
var deviceComponent = MixerLineInfoComponentType.Wavein;
WindowsMixer.MuteAllDevices(deviceComponent);
```

Example to Enumerate all Input devices;

```
var deviceComponent = MixerLineInfoComponentType.Wavein;
var inputDevices = WindowsMixer.FindAllDevices(deviceComponent).ToArray();

var deviceEnumeration = string.Join("\n", inputDevices.Select(i =>
     i.SourceMixerLineInfo.target.productName));

Console.WriteLine(deviceEnumeration);
```

You can also use this to mute single devices at a time.

Comment: Sadly, .NET Framework 4.5 isn't compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 libraries. I did try it anyway to check out the samples, as I might be able to update the project to 4.6.1 at a later date.
Besides that, the fact that whilst the listing does show multiple volume and mute nodes, it doesn't specify the node's owner name nor has individual controls on each node, making the muting of a specific node of a specific auxiliary input.